# use copyright sign in i18n translation

Tags: reactjs, i18next, language-translation

I'm using i18n to translate my multi language react project.
I'm going to use copyright sign (&copy;) in my translation file. but it couldn't show the © sign and is showing the "&copy;" as a string.

this is my translation file:

```
"footer.copyright":
    "Copyright &copy; {{current_year}} {{COMPANY_NAME}}. All right reserved."
```

and I put that in my components like this:

```
<Trans
   i18nKey="footer.copyright"
   values={{ current_year, COMPANY_NAME}}
/>
```

I want to show: Copyright © 2020 MY COMPANY. All right reserved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the Unicode codepoint `\u00A9` instead of `&copy;`, that could be the issue.